# How to pull Microsoft Azure Event Hub instance details like event hub connection string ,from our application

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-eventhub

I am using Microsoft Azure Resource Manager API 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/listbyresourcegroup
I am able to pull all event hub namespaces under particular 
Subscription & resource group . But I am unable to pull event hub instances details like , event hub connection string and name of availabile event hub instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seams that there is no such option in the rest api you mentioned.

You should use the following apis for fetching event hub connection string and name of event hub instances respectively.

1. For names of event hub instances, use this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/eventhubs/listbynamespace), you need to specify the namespce:

> GET
>   https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/{namespaceName}/eventhubs?api-version=2017-04-01

2. For connection strings, use this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/eventhubs/listkeys). You should specify namespace / event hub name / connection string name:

> POST
>   https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/{namespaceName}/eventhubs/{eventHubName}/authorizationRules/{authorizationRuleName}/ListKeys?api-version=2017-04-01

Response for connection string of event hub:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input , It worked , do we have any api to pull/Create connection string name/ Policy ?

Comment: Sorry for late response. For creation, you can use this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/eventhubs/createorupdateauthorizationrule). For pull, you can use this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/eventhubs/listauthorizationrules)